# Why is max HTTP connections still configured using ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit?

Tags: c#, http, .net-core

In creating a bot that queries a web API recently, I noticed that it still seems to be the case that if you want to limit concurrent connections by the HTTP client, you have to set a centralized property `DefaultConnectionLimit` on `ServicePointManager`.  Isn't this a very outdated way to configure things given .NET's DI system these days?  Why isn't there an option to set a connection limit on an individual `HttpClient` (maybe you want different HTTP clients to have different limits)?  Is it just because of some legacy implementation or is there a technical justification for the centralized connection limit configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can achieve this by configuring `HttpMessageHandler`. For example something like the following:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<SomeHttpClient>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(x => new HttpClientHandler
    {
        MaxConnectionsPerServer = 100
    });
```